# Woocommerce issue - can't change the order status, 'Change' / 'Update' button is not present

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found a strange behaviour with Woocommerce plugin. I am using : 
WooCommerce version 6.7.0 
Wordpress version 6.0.1 
Theme OceanWP 3.3.3

There is an order which is in 'processing' state. When I open that order from admin page and try to change the state to any other state (say 'delivered' etc.), I can't do this because the '**Update**' button is not present in the page. (I hope name of the button is not wrong)

Strange thing is that I can change the state of the same order using 'Bulk option -> Apply' operation, no issue. But not within the 'order detail admin page' as '**Update**' button is not present.

Also, even two days back I didn't face any such issue, I could change the order status seamlessly by clicking on the '**Update**' button.

I didn't install any new plugin recently, also I didn't insert any new code that could break the feature. I have 'git' setup and I verified that.

What could be the reason of this sudden change of WooCommerce functionality ? Is there any WooCommerce settings that I missed ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: You can see the order action here]

If you are not able to see the button here this may be because of theme or plugin conflict change your current theme with Wordpress default woo-commerce theme and deactivate all plugins and start activating the theme one by one to find out if any plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: But I have git set up in 'public_html/wp-content' folder and I don't see any modification except in 'upload' folder which shouldn't have any effect on this issue.

Comment: It's my bad, the 'Order actions' section was displaced from right side column to somewhere middle of the page, so I couldn't see it above 'Order notes' section. Those section can be dragged and placed in some other place of the page, I was not aware of that. Sorry for the confusion,  my problem is solved. Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can change it from here, If you think its automatically change then you can add a plugin for activity so you can easily track it if any user changed it or something like this.

Comment: It's my bad, the 'Order actions' section was displaced from right side column to somewhere middle of the page, so I couldn't see it above 'Order notes' section. Those section can be dragged and placed in some other place of the page, I was not aware of that. Sorry for the confusion, my problem is solved. Thank's for your time.

Comment: Good to hear that issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you configured woocommerce have you checked if this option was showing before?

You can try upgrading to Wordpress and Woocommerce's latest version if the theme and plugins are not conflicting.

Comment: Yes, it was working perfectly fine 2 days back and I didn't upgrade any plugin or theme.

Comment: Switch your current theme to the woo-commerce default one then check.

Comment: WooCommerce default theme -- do you mean "WooCommerce Storefront" ?

Comment: I have deactivated all the plugins except WooCommerce, but no luck.

Comment: Yes the  "Woocommerce Storefront"